# Radio Buttons not coming

Tags: jsp, radio-button

This is a very basic question. I have created two radio buttons in my jsp page. Buttons are coming but the user can select both buttons. It is not behaving as radio button. Here is my jsp code

```
 <div class="list list2" id = "userPreference">
         <div id= "preferenceResultMessage"></div>
         <input type="radio" name="sortByPrice" value=""/> <span class="text">Sort by Price </span>
         <input type="radio" name="sortByTime" value=""/>  <span class="text">Sort by Delivery time</span>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" onclick = "loadPreference()" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To link the radio buttons, they need to have the same name attribute.  For example:

```
<div id= "preferenceResultMessage"></div>
         <input type="radio" name="sortBy" value=""/> <span class="text">Sort by Price </span>
         <input type="radio" name="sortBy" value=""/> <span class="text">Sort by Delivery time</span>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" onclick = "loadPreference()" />
 </div>
```

You can [see this in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/vvra8853/).